# Last two rows not formatted, but are copied over correctly, with no reason why

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason when this script exports to the PO Tracking tab the last two rows are left unformated... I don't know why as far as I can tell the code should take that into consideration. If someone can take a peek at the code below and show me where I need to adjust it be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PO_Tracking()

Dim wsPOD As Worksheet
Dim wsPOT As Worksheet
Dim wsPOA As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, Er As Long

Set wsPOD = Sheets("PO Data")
Set wsPOT = Sheets("PO Tracking")
Set wsPOA = Sheets("PO Archive")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

With wsPOD
    'first bring columns F:G up to match their line
    For Each cel In Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(5), .Columns(6))

        If cel = vbNullString And cel.Offset(, -2) <> vbNullString Then
            .Range(cel.Offset(1), cel.Offset(1, 1)).Copy cel
            cel.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    Next

    'now fil columns A:D to match PO Date and PO#
    For Each cel In Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(5), .Columns(1))

        If cel = vbNullString And cel.Offset(, 5) <> vbNullString Then
            .Range(cel.Offset(-1), cel.Offset(-1, 3)).Copy cel
        End If
    Next
'Blow away rows that are useless
    lastrow = wsPOD.Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row
    wsPOD.Range("M5:P5").Copy wsPOD.Range("M6:P" & lastrow)
    Calculate

    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Columns("N"))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>Different"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Columns("P"))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    lastrow = wsPOD.Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row
    wsPOD.UsedRange.Copy Sheets.Add.Range("A1")


'Final Adjustments before transfering over to new sheet.
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("A")).Cut .Range("Q1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("D")).Cut .Range("R1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("C")).Cut .Range("S1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("B")).Cut .Range("T1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("G")).Cut .Range("U1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("F")).Cut .Range("V1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("Q:V")).Copy wsPOT.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .Delete
    End With

    lastrow = wsPOD.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    wsPOT.Range("R1:X1").Copy
    wsPOT.Range("B3:H" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    wsPOT.Range("N2:O2").Copy wsPOT.Range("N3:O" & lastrow)
    wsPOT.Range("P1:Q1").Copy wsPOT.Range("I3:J" & lastrow)
    wsPOT.Range("K3:K" & lastrow).Borders.Weight = xlThin
End With



Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Here is the excel sheet.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Last%20two%20rows.xlsm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you stepped through the code, line by line, to see exactly what it's doing to your spreadsheet? By far, that is the best way to see why your code is failing because you will see the fail line once you run it. Also, it's the best way to get a great answer from other developer's, because you can pinpoint your question if you still don't understand why it breaks, making it easier for us to troubleshoot.

I stepped through the code a little bit - since I helped build it! It doesn't even seem to be doing what it should, according to what I remember.

Comment: I'm going through each step as we speak.  Right now I've gotten it to the point where I am moving everything over without any issues.  I am attempting to get it where I copy all cells between Q:V on the "activesheet" and paste them on another.  That is where I'm working through now.

Comment: I'm running into the issue of how to copy the data over. I am running into an issue where it copies but it doesn't format the last two rows. I can't figure out why really.

Comment: Actually I'm getting an issue where the last cell is not where the last cell of text is, but where it choose to be. it seems.

Comment: @Matt Ridge: so the problem is here? lastrow = wsPOD.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row? WHen you set that variable is what you think it should be? (Sorry, I can't run code because in your workbook, it appears cell references are off)

Comment: Solved it... you hit it, but it was meant to be wsPOT, I changed it just as you were typing it... and it runs now.  I've been re-reading this code too long today I think it's time for me to go home. Thanks again.

Comment: @Matt Ridge: instead of lastrow = wsPOD.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row try this: lastrow = wsPOD.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Comment: Awesome. Ignore my last comment then, since it may not be relevant with the wks change. FYI, the reason I answered like I did was because you really didn't show any debugging efforts in your question. It's not too becoming for a person to say, in essence, "here's my code, it's not working, can you fix it." So, i felt in this instance the answer was to have you debug, step-by-step, which in this instance, did solve your problem!

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I realized that after the fact :)